# Auto-populating a Django model field using JavaScript fails consistently

Tags: javascript, html, django, dom, django-models

I have a model named `Package`. It has fields named, `diagnosis`, `treatment`, `patient_type`, `max_fractions` and `total_package`. The fields `diagnosis`, `treatment` and `patient_type` have foreign keys defined in separate individual classes, making `diagnosis`, `treatment` and `patient_type` choice fields. Now what I want is to auto-populate the `max_fractions` and `total_package` fields whenever `treatment` and `patient_type`'s values are selected. I was suggested to use JavaScript to accomplish that. I tried and wrote the codes but to no avail. I'm trying it on `max_fractions` field first, when I succeed in doing that, I will do it for all the needed fields.

Can anyone help me on this, it will be much appreciated.

Here are my models:

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    diagnosis=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.diagnosis

class Treatment(models.Model):
    treatment=models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.treatment

class PatientType(models.Model):
    patient_type=models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient_type


class Package(models.Model):
    rt_number=ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    diagnosis=models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, on_delete=CASCADE)
    treatment=ForeignKey(Treatment, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    max_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    total_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class DiagnosisForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Diagnosis
        fields='__all__'

class TreatmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Treatment
        fields='__all__'

class PatientTypeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=PatientType
        fields='__all__'

class PackageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Package
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
           "max_fractions" : forms.NumberInput(attrs={"onfocus":"mf();"}),
        }
```

**views.py:**

```
def package_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_package=PackageForm(request.POST, prefix='package_form')
        fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm(request.POST, prefix='diagnosis_form')
        fm_treatment=TreatmentForm(request.POST, prefix='treatment_form')
        fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm(request.POST, prefix='patien_type_form')
        if fm_package.is_valid() and fm_diagnosis.is_valid() and fm_treatment.is_valid() and fm_patient_type.is_valid():
            diagnosis=fm_diagnosis.save()
            treatment=fm_treatment.save()
            patient_type=fm_patient_type.save()
            package=fm_package.save(False)
            package.diagnosis=diagnosis
            package.treatment=treatment
            package.patient_type=patient_type
            package.save()
            fm_package=PackageForm(prefix='package_form')
            fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm(prefix='diagnosis_form')
            fm_treatment=TreatmentForm(prefix='treatment_form')
            fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm(prefix='patien_type_form')
        return render (request, 'account/package.html', {'form2':fm_diagnosis, 'form3':fm_treatment, 'form4':fm_patient_type, 'form5':fm_package})
    else:
        fm_package=PackageForm(prefix='package_form')
        fm_diagnosis=DiagnosisForm(prefix='diagnosis_form')
        fm_treatment=TreatmentForm(prefix='treatment_form')
        fm_patient_type=PatientTypeForm(prefix='patien_type_form')
        return render (request, 'account/package.html', {'form2':fm_diagnosis, 'form3':fm_treatment, 'form4':fm_patient_type, 'form5':fm_package})
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function mf(){
    tt=document.getElementById("id_package_form-treatment").value;
    ptt=document.getElementById("id_package_form-patient_type").value;
    max=document.getElementById("id_package_form-max_fractions").value;
    if (tt=="YEO5" && ptt=="RUHPE")
    max=40;
    else if (tt=="D4EG" && ptt=="KILEU")
    max=40;
    else if (tt=="5GED" && ptt=="IMRA")
    max=40;
}
```

**the template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Package Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form2.as_p}}
        {{form3.as_p}}
        {{form4.as_p}}
        {{form5.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


    <script src="{% static 'account/js/myjs.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**URLs:**

```
path('package/', views.package_view),
```

Now, when I opened the webpage and clicked on the view page source, I saw that the values of the choice fields were displayed as autoincremented numbers. So my JS code can not read the desired values of the selections.

**HTML source page view:**

```
<p><label for="id_package_form-treatment">Treatment:</label> <select name="package_form-treatment" required id="id_package_form-treatment">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">YEO5</option>

  <option value="2">2DRT</option>

  <option value="3">D4EG</option>

  <option value="4">5GED</option>

  <option value="5"></option>

</select></p>
<p><label for="id_package_form-patient_type">Patient type:</label> <select name="package_form-patient_type" required id="id_package_form-patient_type">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">RUHPE</option>

  <option value="2">KILEU</option>

  <option value="3">IMRA</option>

  <option value="5"></option>

</select></p>
<p><label for="id_package_form-max_fractions">Max fractions:</label> <input type="number" name="package_form-max_fractions" onfocus="mf();" required id="id_package_form-max_fractions"></p>
```

What is going wrong with my codes, I can not find it. This has been the most disappointing experience of mine as a beginner. It's been 4 days that I'm trying to get over this episode. Many people here have tried to help me with useful suggestions, which I'm really grateful for, but I'm still stuck here. Someone please get me out of here. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get text of option using `tt_select.options[tt_select.selectedIndex].text` where `tt_select` is your select-box same for other as well and then compare this value in your if statements to set required values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function mf() {
  tt_select = document.getElementById("id_package_form-treatment");
  tt = tt_select.options[tt_select.selectedIndex].text;
  ptt_select = document.getElementById("id_package_form-patient_type");
  ptt = ptt_select.options[ptt_select.selectedIndex].text;
  max = document.getElementById("id_package_form-max_fractions");
  if (tt == "YEO5" && ptt == "RUHPE")
    max.value = 400;
  else if (tt == "D4EG" && ptt == "KILEU")
    max.value = 40;
  else if (tt == "5GED" && ptt == "IMRA")
    max.value = 408;
  else
    max.value = ""
}
```

```html
<p><label for="id_package_form-treatment">Treatment:</label>
  <select name="package_form-treatment" required id="id_package_form-treatment">
    <option value="" selected>---------</option>

    <option value="1">YEO5</option>

    <option value="2">2DRT</option>

    <option value="3">D4EG</option>

    <option value="4">5GED</option>

    <option value="5"></option>

  </select>
</p>
<p><label for="id_package_form-patient_type">Patient type:</label>
  <select name="package_form-patient_type" required id="id_package_form-patient_type">
    <option value="" selected>---------</option>

    <option value="1">RUHPE</option>

    <option value="2">KILEU</option>

    <option value="3">IMRA</option>

    <option value="5"></option>

  </select>
</p>
<p><label for="id_package_form-max_fractions">Max fractions:</label> <input type="number" name="package_form-max_fractions" onfocus="mf();" required id="id_package_form-max_fractions"></p>
```

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!! THANK YOU!!! THANKS A LOTTT!!! HAHA, I think I should have asked the correct question! I should have asked how to capture the text of the select tag or something. Anyway, thanks again. Cheers!!